# Loading UUIDs from MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, uuid

i got a database where I use UUIDs as a primary key. I store the uuids as a binary(16) using java. To save an entry I use following

```
public boolean saveEntry(UUID id , String, name, int p1, int p2) throws SQLException
{
    byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(uuidBytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).putLong(id.getMostSignificantBits())
            .putLong(id.getLeastSignificantBits());
    String updateQuery = "INSERT INTO " + databaseTableName + " (ID, Name, p1, p2) "
            + "VALUES " + "(?, ?, ?, ?) "
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
        // write the id in the workflow table
        statement = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
        statement.setBytes(1, uuidBytes);
        statement.setString(2, name);
        statement.setInt(3, p1);
        statement.setInt(4, p2);
        statement.execute();
```

This part is working and I can see my entries in the database.

However as soon as I try to load the entry with this:

```
public Workflow loadEntry(UUID id) throws SQLException
{
    byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(uuidBytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).putLong(id.getMostSignificantBits())
            .putLong(id.getLeastSignificantBits());
    String query = "SELECT " + "* " + "FROM " + databaseTableName + " WHERE " + databaseTableName
            + ".ID = ?";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try
    {
        preparedStatement = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setBytes(1, uuidBytes);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
```

I get following mistake:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?' at line 1

I'm not quite sure what the cause pf the error is. I know that using `id.toString().replaceAll("-", "")` works, but I'm not sure about perfomance and functionallity of this way. So is there any way I can get around this Solution?

Comment: What is the type of the `ID` column in the actual table?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/store-uuid-optimized-way

Comment: binary(16) @TimBiegeleisen